# int(primitive) value not getting typecasted to long(primitive) implicitly

Tags: java, int, long-integer

My question appears very simple.

```
int i =99999;
long square = i*i;
System.out.println(square);   //prints 1409865409 - incorrect value

int i = 99999;
long square = (long) i*i;
System.out.println(square);  // prints 9999800001 - correct value
```

It looks to be the range issue of int. 
But shouldn't it typecast the product to long implicitly?
What am I missing here?
I know how to use Math.pow(double,double) function and it works perfectly. But
I want to know the reason for above output.

TIA.

Comment: `i * i` is always an `int`, regardless of whether you assign it to a `long`.

Comment: *"But shouldn't it typecast the product to long implicitly?"* Yes, that is what happens. The _product_ will be widened to `long`, not the _factors_.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, the result is first computed as an `int`, and only then converted to a `long`.

Therefore the wrong result.

---

In the second case, `i` is converted to a `long` before computing the result because `(long)` (cast to `long`) has a higher precedence than `*`.

Therefore the right result.

Answer (score 3):

You have fallen prey to an operator precedence error. This line:

```
long square = (long) i*i;
```

actually does this:

```
long square = ((long) i)*i;
```

This is important, because when you multiply 99999, you get a number too large to represent as an `int`. This line:

```
long square = i*i;
```

squares `i`, causing an overflow error, then casts the result to a `long` and assigns it to `square`. The other line casts the first factor to a `long`, forcing it to cast the second factor to a `long` as well, before the calculation takes place.